# onclick scroll event - syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

Trying to have it scroll based on if it was clicked on the left or right side of the page. Doesn't seem to work..  Perhaps my syntax is incorrect or the method i'm using to find the left or right side of the page is?

with `<body onclick="scrollevent()">` :

```
 <script>
 function scrollevent()
 { 
    var y=0;
    var pwidth = $('#slideshow').width();
    var mouseY = ev.clientY;

    if (mouseY<(pwidth/2) {
        $('#slideshow').animate({scrollLeft: "+=400"});
     }
     else{
        $('#slideshow').animate({scrollLeft: "-=400"});
    }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Does it not work at all?  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: unexpected token { at line>>>>>> if (mouseY<(pwidth/2) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pageX` and not *pageY* property of the `event` object, try the following:

> The mouse position relative to the left edge of the document.

```
$(document).click(function(e){  // or $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
   var mp = e.pageX;
   var w = $(window).width() / 2;
   if (mp < w) {
        $('#slideshow').animate({scrollLeft: "+=400"});
   } else {
        $('#slideshow').animate({scrollLeft: "-=400"});
   } 
})
```

Please note that there is a syntax error in your code, you have missed a `)`:

```
if (mouseY<(pwidth/2) {
```

should be:

```
if ( mouseY < (pwidth/2) ) {
```

Comment: http://elijahhoffman.com/testsite/ < no dice, do i still need to call this function via the body onclick? i'm not great with javascript.

Comment: @rootsup no, you should remove the `onclick` attribute of the body.

Comment: @rootsup ... and if you put that code in a `.js` file you can include it on any page, rather than duplicating it on every page where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

> The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric **CSS property**.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

.scrollLeft() is a jQuery function, not css property.

**upd:** my bad, as docs says:

> In addition to style properties, some non-style properties such as scrollTop and scrollLeft, as well as custom properties, can be animated.

Comment: the scroll function works fine when called on it's own, it's the rest

Answer (score 0):

You are using clientY.

Use clientX instead of clientY to check whether it is clicked on left or right side of the page.

Demo can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/UT9xK/

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
if (mouseY<(pwidth/2) {
```

is missing a closing `)`.  Try this:

```
if (mouseY<(pwidth/2)) {
```